# Insert image between \title and \author

Tags: graphics

I am trying to insert an image on the title page **between** the actual title and the author. 
I tried using `\titlepic{\includegraphics[width=70mm]{img/myimg.png}}` but this always inserts the image after title, the author and the date. 
Is there a way to insert the image exactly between the title and the author?
Here is an example document showcasing the problem:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{titlepic}
\usepackage{graphicx}

\title{LaTeX Test Document}
\author{John Smith }
\date{September 2018}
\titlepic{\includegraphics[width=70mm]{myimage.png}}

\begin{document}
\maketitle
\end{document}
```

Results in the following output:

[image]

Comment: the formatting of the title depends totally on the document class and you haven't said what class you are using or how `\titlepic`,  which isn't  standard command, is defined.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle I updated my question.

Comment: `article` class doesn't define `\includegraphics` or `\titlepic` I can guess which package you are using for the first (since I wrote it) but no idea about the second, if you are using some package that redefines title handling then you need to ask about _that package_. In general questions should almost always have a small complete document that shows the problem and allows people to test answers.

Comment: You should take a look at the `titling` package, which defines tools to customise the `\maketitle` command.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle This is the titlepic package: https://github.com/ttencate/titlepic
I'll create a little test document in a minute.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle I added a test document.

Comment: sure but by now juanumi's answer seems fine to me

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could try `titling` package:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{graphicx}

\usepackage{titling}
\pretitle{\begin{center}\fontsize{18bp}{18bp}\selectfont}
    \posttitle{\vspace{14bp}\par\includegraphics[width=70mm]{respect-cat}\par\end{center}}
\preauthor{\begin{center}\fontsize{14bp}{14bp}\selectfont}
    \postauthor{\par\end{center}}
\predate{\begin{center}}
    \postdate{\par\end{center} }    

\title{titling-proof}
\author{Kyu96}
\date{\today}

\begin{document}

\maketitle

\end{document}
```

[image]

You can play with the sizes ...